# From JSON data to Dictionary with multiple key values in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, timestamp

I have a JSON formatted file and i have to deal with sequential timestamps and actions performed in a specific timestamp. Due to approximation timestamps sometimes are the same so i'd like to create a dictionary with the single timestamp as a key and count the actions performed per timestamp. I have created two lists, one of sequential timestamps, and the other of sequential actions (data in JSON are sequential) :

```
timestamp_list.append(timestamp)
actions_list.append(action)
```

I'd like to create a specified list of actions like

```
actions_set = ['action1','action2','action3']
```

and count how many actions in the actions_set list occurs per timestamps.

Trying to create a dictionary instead automatically removes the duplicates keys:

```
action_dict[timestamp] = []
action_dict[timestamp].append(action)
```

I've solved instead the problem of counting the actions (without filtering them with a list) counting the duplicate timestamps and printing out the numbers of actions performed each instant:

```
action_count = [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(timestamp_list)]
```

The actions and timestamps are saved in unicode format, do you guys have any advice or solution to the problem? Thanks.

Comment: is saving as unicode the problem ?

Comment: no i think i can do a type conversion of datetime for timestamps and str for the actions.. Problem is that if i create dictionary automatically (the JSON parsers reads the file line by line and timestamps and actions are stored sequentially) i'll have only different timestamps as keys and last action in that particular timestamp. I'd like to count how many values a key have and print out the result, also i'd like that this counting is limited to a specified set of actions not every actions i read from JSON file.. (i've solved that problem with the action_count list)

Comment: As a matter of good practice, you should probably avoid using a variable name `xyz_set` for a variable that isn't actually a `set`.

Comment: @user3782691 can you show a part of the Json file ? (add to your question)